# Creating a streaming Conduit Source with postgresql-simple

Tags: haskell, conduit, postgresql-simple

`postgresql-simple` provides functions for streaming queries, e.g.

```
fold 
  :: (FromRow row, ToRow params)
  => Connection -> Query -> params -> a -> (a -> row -> IO a) -> IO a
```

I want to create a conduit source which takes full advantage of streaming.

```
mySource :: (FromRow row, Monad m) => Source m row
```

Unfortunately, because `IO` appears in a contravariant position (I think?) in `fold`, I'm really struggling with the types. The following type-checks, but folds the entire stream before yielding values.

```
getConduit :: Connection -> IO (C.ConduitM () Event IO ())
getConduit conn = fold_ conn queryEventRecord CL.sourceNull foo
  where
    foo :: C.ConduitM () Event IO () -> Event -> IO (C.ConduitM () Event IO ())
    foo cond evt = pure (cond >> C.yield evt)
```

Any pointers on how to implement this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: In persistent-postgresql, we dropped down to [postgresql-libpq](https://www.stackage.org/package/postgresql-libpq) to implement this behavior. I'm not sure that postgresql-simple can do this (besides with the `TMChan` approach @Alec mentioned).

Comment: There is a `pipes-postgresql-simple` with a function, [`query`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-postgresql-simple-0.1.2.0/docs/Pipes-PostgreSQL-Simple.html#v:query) for this; it is basically using the strategy @Alec mentions (implemented with `pipes-concurrency` though) as you can see in the implementation of [`produceIO`](https://github.com/ocharles/pipes-postgresql-simple/blob/master/src/Pipes/PostgreSQL/Simple.hs#L117)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One (not so nice) way to go about this it to

- make a new [`TMChan`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-chans-3.0.0.4/docs/Control-Concurrent-STM-TMChan.html#t:TMChan) to receive rows
- set [`foreach_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.2.1/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html#v:forEach_) to just dump rows into this channel
- finally use [`stm-conduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-conduit-3.0.0/docs/Data-Conduit-TMChan.html) to make a source out of the channel

I don't have the means to test this off-hand, but the following should work

```
import Conduit
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple (foreach_)
import Data.Conduit.TMChan (sourceTMChan)
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TMChan (newTMChanIO, writeTMChan, atomically)

mySource :: (FromRow row, MonadIO m) => Connection -> Query -> IO (Source m row)
mySource connection query = do
  chan <- newTMChanIO
  forEach_ connection query (atomically . writeTMChan chan)
  pure (sourceTMChan chan)
```

If only we had `forEach_ :: (MonadIO m, FromRow r) => Connection -> Query -> (r -> m ()) -> m ()` this might be easier...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modification of Alec's above that compiles and runs. `mkPgSource` is the general function that Alec referred to at the end of his post.

```
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.FromRow
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.ToRow
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (MonadIO)
import Data.Conduit.TMChan (sourceTMChan)
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TMChan (newTMChanIO, writeTMChan, 
closeTMChan, TMChan)
import GHC.Conc (atomically, forkIO)
import Conduit

--closes the channel after action is done to terminate the source
mkPgSource :: (MonadIO m, FromRow r) => ((r -> IO ()) -> IO ()) -> IO (Source m r)
mkPgSource action = do
  chan <- newTMChanIO
  _ <- forkIO $ do action $ atomically . (writeTMChan chan)
               atomically $ closeTMChan chan
  pure $ sourceTMChan chan

sourceQuery :: (ToRow params, FromRow r, MonadIO m) =>
     Connection -> Query -> params -> IO (Source m r)
sourceQuery conn q params = mkPgSource $ forEach conn q params

sourceQuery_ :: (FromRow r, MonadIO m) => Connection -> Query -> IO 
(Source m r)
sourceQuery_ conn q = mkPgSource $ forEach_ conn q
```